# Travelling around Japan on a cruise ship

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, japan, filipino-citizens, cruising

we are Filipino citizen who will travel around japan via a cruise ship for a week and will disembark in Hong Kong, do we still need to have a Japanese visitor visa for the duration of the cruise?

Comment: Filipinos are required to have a visa to visit Japan, so if you plan to go ashore at ports of call you will need either a visa or shore pass.  You would need to ask the cruise line if they provide shore passes or if visas are mandated.

Comment: [Relaxed regulations for cruise ships passengers](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/nyukan2015/index.html) went into effect in 2015, but you need to confirm whether your ship is "designated by the Minister of Justice."

Answer (score 1):

The [Japan National Tourism Organization](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/arrange/essential/visa.html) lists the Philippines as a country that doesn't have a *Reciprocal Visa Exemption Arrangement*, requiring you to apply for a visa.

You can find more information about what's required and how to apply for a visa for Philippine Nationals on the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/philippine.html).